# Android global writable folder

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to put firebird embedded running on android.
The problem is that fb put temporary files on /data/local/tmp.

That folder don't seems to have write permissions, at least on Android 6, and fb fails to start.

Do android have a good place to put this files?
That place must be available globally and can't be cleaned by external services.

Regards
jGoncalves

Answer (score 0):

> That place must be available globally and can't be cleaned by external
>   services.

Those two things are mutually exclusive.

You can either put it in external storage where any app can read and write it (if they've been granted the respective permissions), or you can put it in app private storage where only your app can read it.

If you want to export data from a database to other apps, the right way is to wrap it with a content provider and publish your content provider interface to other interested apps.

I don't know Firebase, but I'm guessing that it can't support multiple processes reading and writing to the same DB file.